# Will a max-width on a span cause text in it to shrink?

Tags: scalability, font-size

Trying to make a scalable font size with only HTML/CSS. Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Fonts won't scale that way. The text will simply fall off, or wrap.